# How can I sort descending the result of a Group by?

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table `messages` with the following fields:

`id`, `surname`, `name`, `message`, `message_date`

I am trying to write the correct query so as to display all the rows grouped by `surname` and sorted by date in descending order (I want the group to display only the most recent record, based on `message_date`).

For example, if I have the following records:

```
 - 1, John   Doe, my message, 2016-04-24 11:13:24
 - 2, Johnny Doe, hello, 2016-05-22 15:23:05
 - 3, John Doe, another message, 2016-05-23 16:10:07
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

```
 - 3, John   Doe, another message, 2016-05-23 16:10:07 
 - 2, Johnny Doe, hello, 2016-05-22 15:23:05
```

I tried to use the following query but it doesn't work properly:

```
$sql="SELECT *
FROM   messages
WHERE  (id, surname, name, message, message_date) IN (
      SELECT id, surname, name, message, MAX(message_date)
      FROM messages
      GROUP BY surname)";
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to add `ORDER BY message_date DESC`?

Comment: @jakob What would that help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you are also using `message` for the `IN()` statement, which is different for between each message . Discard it and this should work:

```
$sql="SELECT *
      FROM   messages
      WHERE  (surname, name, message_date) IN (SELECT surname, name, MAX(message_date)
                                                   FROM messages
                                                   GROUP BY surname, name)
      ORDER BY message_date DESC";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The data is not grouped, the query result is: 3, John, Doe, another message, 2016-05-23 16:10:07; 2, Jonny, Doe, hello, 2016-05-22 15:23:05; 1, John, Doe, my message, 2016-04-24 11:13:24

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated ? This should work:

```
SELECT id,surname,name,message_date FROM messages 
GROUP BY surname
ORDER BY message_date DESC
```

**Edit1:** Ok now I see your problem. The Group By happens before the ORder BY

I tried it myself and this works better:

```
SELECT x.* FROM  messages x
JOIN(SELECT surname,max(message_date) max_date FROM messages GROUP BY surname) y
ON y.surname=x.surname
AND y.max_date=x.message_date
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the query doesn't work properly. The data is grouped, but the sorting is not made in descending order. the query result is: 2, Jonny, Doe, 2016-05-22, 15:23:05; 1, John, Doe, 2016-04-24, 11:13:24. Somehow the GROUP BY and ORDER BY do not function properly together.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql="SELECT id, surname, name, message, message_date FROM messages 
       GROUP BY surname ORDER BY TIME(message_date) DESC";
```

Comment: Thank you! The data is grouped, but GROUP BY data is not sorted in descending order. The query result is: 2, Jonny, Doe, 2016-05-22, 15:23:05; 1, John, Doe, 2016-04-24, 11:13:24.

Comment: You want to sorting by date or time?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this by using the following query:

`$sql="SELECT * FROM
(SELECT surname, MAX(message_date) AS message_date FROM messages GROUP BY surname)
AS x JOIN messages USING (surname, message_date) ORDER BY message_date DESC";`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this when I was facing similar situation. However, I couldn't use the posted answers as I was applying other filters. So, I came up with a different solution. Hope it helps (assuming id is unique) .

```
SELECT id, surname, name, message_date FROM messages as a 
WHERE a.`id` = (SELECT b.`id` FROM `messages` WHERE a.`surname` = b.`surname`
ORDER BY b.`id` DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
GROUP BY surname ORDER BY message_date DESC
```